# Combination > Advanced Timeline causes "ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**Steps To Replicate**

1. Download `HIGHCHARTS 4.1.9` from http://www.highcharts.com/download
2. Open `index.html`.
3. Click on `Combinations > Advanced timeline`.
4. The following error is shown in Firebug and no chart is displayed:

`ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined /Highcharts-4.1.9/js/modules/exporting.js Line 24`

`ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined /Highcharts-4.1.9/examples/combo-timeline/index.htm Line 280`

**What I've Tried**

I changed the script paths at the end of:

```
/Highcharts-4.1.9/examples/combo-timeline/index.html
```

From:

```
<script src="../../js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="../js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

However, this still produces the error:

```
ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
/Highcharts-4.1.9/examples/combo-timeline/index.htm
Line 280
```

I changed the reference to jQuery in `/combo-timeline/index.htm` from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

which then produces this error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
/Highcharts-4.1.9/examples/combo-timeline/index.htm
Line 204
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

The [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-timeline/) was working, so I downloaded the following:

https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js
https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js

And used the jQuery version used in the fiddle:

```
jQuery Core 1.9.1
```

And the chart loads now and there are no errors.